# how to overwrite omega 960 grid margin?

Tags: theming

What is the correct way to overwrite the Omega theme stylesheet, so that the margin of `.grid-1` is 0 instead of 10px?

I tried to specify this style:

```
.grid-1 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

in two stylesheets: 
/sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/mytheme-alpha-default-normal.css -> this one is not loaded at all

/sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/global.css -> this one is overwritten by alpha-default-normal-12.css

The alpha-default-normal-12.css is always at the top of all loaded stylesheets, so it looks like it can't be overwritten. And it contains the styles for all .grid-x margins.

So, how to specify my own margin for a grid?

Answer (score 4):

The best explanation of how to do a custom grid in Omega I have found is in the Omega documentation wiki: [Creating and Setting up a Custom Grid for Omega 3.x](http://groups.drupal.org/node/164684). As the Omega documentation matures, I hope this will move into the main documentation.

The basic idea is below (but see the link above for more details):

1. Copy the appropriate `grids` entries from `alpha.info` into `mytheme.info`. There will be no `grids` entries initially in your `mytheme.info` if you have created a subtheme in the normal way. You will be copying various `grids[alpha_default]` entries. Then edit those entries to be `grids[mytheme_default]`.
2. Generate a new CSS grid file at http://grids.heroku.com/ or http://www.spry-soft.com/grids/. Just use this as a model for the next step, as it does not correspond exactly to the way Omega CSS grid files are written.  The class naming conventions are a little different ("_" vs "-", for instance.
3. Copy the css and png files you need from `sites/all/themes/omega/alpha/css/grid/alpha_default/{normal,wide,narrow,..}/alpha-default-*-*.{css,png}`. to `sites/all/themes/mythemes/css/grid/mytheme_default/{normal,wide,narrow,..}/mytheme-default-*-*.{css,png}`. You will not need all the files unless you are planning to provide a complete set of narrow, normal, and wide 12 and 16-column grids. Just put in the ones you need.
4. If you are changing the default number of columns from 12, don't forget to edit the number-of-column defaults for all the different regions given further down in `mytheme.info`. Otherwise your pages will look wrong because they are using the original default settings.
5. Note you must *also* rename the `mytheme/css/mytheme-alpha-default.css` and `mytheme/css/mytheme-alpha-default-{narrow,normal,wide}.css` files to `mytheme/css/mytheme-mytheme-default*.css`. This is because you have changed the `alpha-default` grids name to `mytheme-default`.

I did all this recently for a design I was given that was 960px wide with no left and right margins. I set up a 60px by 16-column 960px grid.

The [Omega Tools](http://drupal.org/project/omega_tools) module has an incomplete wizard for setting up your own custom grid. Unfortunately, it does very little of the above as of this writing.